Android widget not displaying any data for Listview, just shows the header
I am new to android widgets, and writing this in a sample app. For some reason my widget just displays the widget_toolbar the list view remains empty.
Following this example.
Here is my code:
new_app_widget.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widget_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_error">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
      android:contentDescription="Stock widget" />

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
      android:contentDescription="Stock widget" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:text="Your Stocks"
      android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
      android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/widget_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryDark" />

</LinearLayout>

Here is my list view row code:
list_view_row.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="72dp"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingLeft="16dp"
  android:paddingRight="16dp">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/stock_symbol"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    tools:text="List Widget Item" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/stock_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
    tools:text="Date" />
</LinearLayout>

WidgetDataProvider.java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;
import com.test.FeedReaderContract;
import com.test.FeedReaderDbHelper;
import com.test.MainActivity;
import com.test.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WidgetDataProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

  private Context context;
  private Cursor cursor;
  private Intent intent;

  private Map<String, String> tickers;

  private FeedReaderDbHelper mFeedReaderDbHelper;

  private final static String[] TICKERS = {"AAPL", "TSLA", "CRWD", "SNOW", "AMZN", "GOOGL", "CZR",
      "NFLX", "META", "DDOG", "CELH", "GTLB", "PLTR", "SQ", "ARM"};

  private List<String> mStringList;

  //For obtaining the activity's context and intent
  public WidgetDataProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    this.intent = intent;
  }

  private void initCursor(FeedReaderDbHelper dbHelper){
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
    final long identityToken = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    /**This is done because the widget runs as a separate thread
     when compared to the current app and hence the app's data won't be accessible to it
     because I'm using a content provided **/
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
        BaseColumns._ID,
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE
    };
    cursor = db.query(
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
        projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
        null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
        null,          // The values for the WHERE clause
        null,                   // don't group the rows
        null,                   // don't filter by row groups
        null               // The sort order
    );
    Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(identityToken);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    mFeedReaderDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(context);
    initCursor(mFeedReaderDbHelper);
//    mStringList = new ArrayList<>(tickers.keySet());
    System.out.println("onCreate");
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDataSetChanged() {
    /** Listen for data changes and initialize the cursor again **/
    initCursor(mFeedReaderDbHelper);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    cursor.close();
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return tickers.size();
  }

  @Override
  public RemoteViews getViewAt(int i) {
    /** Populate your widget's single list item **/
    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
    System.out.println("onCreate");
    String name = cursor.getString(
        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE));
//    String date = tickers.get(current);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_view_row);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.stock_symbol,name);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.stock_date,"date");
    return remoteViews;
  }

  @Override
  public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
  }
}

NewAppWidget.java
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import com.test.MainActivity;
import com.test.R;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public class StockWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int appWidgetId) {
      // Construct the RemoteViews object which defines the view of out widget
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
      // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
      setRemoteAdapter(context, views);
      /** PendingIntent to launch the MainActivity when the widget was clicked **/
      Intent launchMain = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingMainIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchMain, 0);
      // TODO: what is this?
//      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.m, pendingMainIntent);
      appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId,R.id.widget_listView);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
      // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
      for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
      }

      super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
      // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
      // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    /** Set the Adapter for out widget **/
    private void setRemoteAdapter(Context context, final RemoteViews views) {
      views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_listView,
          new Intent(context, StockWidgetService.class));
    }
  }
}

StockWidgetService.java
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;

public class StockWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

  @Override
  public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new WidgetDataProvider(this, intent);
  }
}

Added the following in AndroidManifest.xml
<service android:name=".widget.StockWidgetService"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

and
<receiver
    android:name=".widget.NewAppWidget"
    android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
           android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
           android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
</receiver>

new_app_widget_info.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:description="@string/app_widget_description"
  android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
  android:minWidth="110dp"
  android:minHeight="110dp"
  android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
  android:previewLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
  android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
  android:targetCellWidth="2"
  android:targetCellHeight="2"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
  android:widgetCategory="home_screen" />


I have not tested the code but I would suggest you add logs so as to be abble to pinpoint where the failure is actually occuring
